# ggplot2 stacked area chart grouping and summing like terms

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-area-chart

My data first looked like this:

```
year    company cars
2011    toyota  609
2011    honda   710
2011    ford    77
2011    nissan  45
2011    chevy   11
2012    toyota  152
2012    honda   657
2012    ford    128
2012    nissan  159
2012    chevy   322
2013    toyota  907
2013    honda   656
2013    ford    138
2013    nissan  270
2013    chevy   106
2014    toyota  336
2014    honda   957
2014    ford    204
2014    nissan  219
2014    chevy   282
```

I wanted to focus only on toyota and honda and group the smaller companies as "other." I used the code `data$company[data$company != "toyota" & data$company != "honda"] = "other"` and was able to revise the data set with the only companies now being toyota, honda, and other, like so:

```
year    company cars
2011    toyota  609
2011    honda   710
2011    other   77
2011    other   45
2011    other   11
2012    toyota  152
2012    honda   657
2012    other   128
2012    other   159
2012    other   322
2013    toyota  907
2013    honda   656
2013    other   138
2013    other   270
2013    other   106
2014    toyota  336
2014    honda   957
2014    other   204
2014    other   219
2014    other   282
```

From this data, I want to generate a stacked area chart in ggplot. I use this code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=year,y=cars, fill=company)) + geom_area())
```

I'd like the multiple instances of "other" in the same year to group and sum. i.e. the three "other"s in 2014 (204, 219, and 282) will sum and be plotted as 705. However, my plot instead leaves odd blanks in the chart, looking like this:

[image]

Anyone know how to generate stacked area plots so that like terms group and sum?

Comment: I guess you need one entry of `other` for each year, i.e. sum of all `other`.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to aggregate your data first:

```
library(ggplot2)

df_agg <- aggregate(cars ~ year + company, data = df, sum)

ggplot(df_agg, aes(x = year, y = cars, fill = company)) +
  geom_area()
```